# Defining dynamic restrictions for Strategy Testing in MetaTrader 5

Tags: mql5

I would like to optimize a minimum variable (let's call it `minPips`) and a maximum variable (`maxPips`).

Let's say `minPips` can be anywhere within an optimization range of 0 to 100, and `maxPips` is between 50 and 200.

How can I prevent a senseless optimization run with `maxPips<minPips` (e.g. `minPips`=100 and `maxPips`=50)?

Maybe using `OnTester()` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

```
int OnInit()
  {
   if(minPips>=maxPips)
     {
      Alert("parameter minPips must be smaller than maxPips);
      return(INIT_FAILED);// or INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT - doesnt matter
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. So if INIT_FAILED is returned the Strategy Tester omits this optimization run and automatically continues with the next one?

Comment: yes, either `INIT_FAILED` or `INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT` or `-N` where N>=1 is ok to skip that test. But keep in mind that this also does not allow to set EA with such parameters for live trading. If for some reason you DO need to allow such strange parameters in realtime but not in optimization, you should check `IsTesting()` or `IsOptimization()` before that. if using pure `MQL5`, use `MqlInfoInteger(MQL_TESTER)` or `MqlInfoInteger(MQL_OPTIMIZATION)` correspondingly.

Comment: Unfortunately `int OnInit()
{
   if(MQLInfoInteger(MQL_TESTER)==true)
     {
         if(minPips>=maxPips) 
         {
            
return(INIT_FAILED);
         }// or INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT - doesnt matter
     }
     }
}` yielded compilation errors (_'}'-expressions are not allowed on a global scope_). Any ideas, please?

Comment: int OnInit()
  {
   if(MQLInfoInteger(MQL_TESTER))
     {
      if(minPips>=maxPips)
        {
         return(INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT);
        }
     }
   //---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }                You set brackets incorrectly I suppose

Comment: You were right about the brackets, thanks, but even after I fixed them `(int OnInit()
{
if(MQLInfoInteger(MQL_TESTER)) { if(minTrend>=maxTrend) { return(INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT); } } //--- return(INIT_SUCCEEDED); }
}int OnInit()
{
if(MQLInfoInteger(MQL_TESTER)) { if(minTrend>=maxTrend) { return(INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT); } } //--- return(INIT_SUCCEEDED); }
}`) I get optimization results with minTrend>maxTrend, unfortunately (no compilation errors anymore)...

Comment: add MCVE example to proceed

Comment: MCVE meaning "minimum complete verifiable example"? Please see my last comment and paste it as the OnInit()-section into any EA. `minTrend`and  `maxTrend` are additionally declared as input variables.

Comment: yes, full example with minimum details(fix lot, probably fix sl/tp,other simplifications) so that it is possible to reproduce the problem